# Open in Windows Explorer option missing in VS2015

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

So it appears that TFS Source Control Explorer in Visual Studio 2015 is missing an option available in Visual Studio 2013 - "Open in Windows Explorer" when right-clicking a folder. I've looked for this option in Tools > Options without success. Has anyone found a way to get this option back? (yes, I'm aware I can right-click a folder in Solution Explorer, but sometimes you're browsing a repository and it's a huge timesaver to have the option there).
[image: VS 2013 option]
[image: Missing in VS 2015]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option is from Windows Shell Extensions of TFS Power Tools, so you need to install [TFS Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1), then you'll see this option.

Comment: D'oh! Forgot about extensions. Thanks!